# What could be the cause of the Bootstrap menu not working?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

The fact is that the bootstrap itself works and is actively used. Sending the code, would be times for any help!

```
<ul class="top-header-contact-info secondary-menu">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown-toggle">
        <a href="novosti">News</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">The Secret of Your Business Success Find Quickly</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown-toggle">
        <a href="o-nas">About us</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="about-us" class="nav-link">About us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown-toggle">
        <a href="kontaktyi">Contacts</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown-toggle">
        <a href="encziklopediya">Encyclopedia</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this: **data-bs-toggle="dropdown"**

```
<ul class="top-header-contact-info secondary-menu">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
            <a href="novosti">News</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">The Secret of Your Business Success Find Quickly</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
            <a href="o-nas">About us</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="about-us" class="nav-link">About us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown-toggle">
            <a href="kontaktyi">Contacts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown-toggle">
            <a href="encziklopediya">Encyclopedia</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```